# Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to Add a column to a new table and update that column using procedure. But I'm getting 2 errors.

> Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored. Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not
>   enough values

Don't Know how to figure out them. Please help me!!

```
ALTER TABLE emp1
  ADD Bonus integer;

set serveroutput on

CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure proc2_update

AS

BEGIN

   dbms_output.put_line('Truncate Table emp1');

   execute immediate 'truncate table emp1';

   dbms_output.put_line('Truncated Table emp1 successfully');

   dbms_output.put_line('Insert into Table emp1');

   insert into emp1 select * from emp;

   dbms_output.put_line('Inserted into Table emp1 successfully');

   dbms_output.put_line('Update Table emp1');

   if Deptno= 10 then 

  update emp1 set Bonus = sal * 10/100;

  Elsif Deptno= 20 then 

  update emp1 set Bonus = sal * 20/100;

  elsif Deptno= 30 then 

  update emp1 set Bonus = sal * 30/100;

  else 

  update emp1 set Bonus = sal * 40/100;

  end if;

   END proc2_update;
```

/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in this line:

```
insert into emp1 select * from emp;
```

It tells you that not all columns of `emp1` are matching with those of `emp`.

Either explicitly give all the fields or update the tables to let their columns match.

I think your procedure should look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure proc2_update
AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Truncate Table emp1');
  execute immediate 'truncate table emp1';
  dbms_output.put_line('Truncated Table emp1 successfully');
  --
  dbms_output.put_line('Insert into Table emp1');
  insert into emp1
  ( col1 -- replace with real column names
  , col2
  )
  select col1
  ,      col2
  from   emp
  ;
   dbms_output.put_line('Inserted into Table emp1 successfully');
  --
  dbms_output.put_line('Update Table emp1');
  update emp1 set Bonus = sal * 10/100 where deptno = 10;
  update emp1 set Bonus = sal * 20/100 where deptno = 20;
  update emp1 set Bonus = sal * 30/100 where deptno = 30;
  update emp1 set Bonus = sal * 40/100 where deptno not in ( 10, 20, 30 );
END proc2_update;
```

Comment: @user3856535: need more help?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with your posted code

Instead of doing like below

```
insert into emp1 select * from emp;
```

specify the column name to be sure off like

```
insert into emp1(col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from emp;
```

Your `UPDATE` looks strange to me. I think you mean to do like

```
update emp1 set Bonus = sal * 10/100 WHERE Deptno= 10;
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree, most likely is the pronlem in the line with insert.
You shouldn't use this form without explicit column list of emp1 and with asterisk from emp.
Altering emp1 or emp will possibly break a lot of your PL/SQL code.